# error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to int

Tags: java, android

I'm getting the **error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to int** error while compiling the android app in Android Studio. The problem is in only one method.

```
private static int get_wx_inx(String str) {
    boolean equalsIgnoreCase = str.equalsIgnoreCase("木");
    int equalsIgnoreCase2 = str.equalsIgnoreCase("火");
    if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("土")) {
        equalsIgnoreCase2 = true;
    }
    if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("金")) {
        equalsIgnoreCase2 = 3;
    }
    return str.equalsIgnoreCase("水") ? 4 : equalsIgnoreCase2;
}
```

I don't know what could be wrong. Can you help me to figure out the problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not bit clear but you might want this:

```
private static int get_wx_inx(String str) {
        if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("木")) {
            return 0;
        } else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("火")) {
            return 1;
        }else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("土")) {
            return 2;
        } else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("金")) {
            return 3;
        } else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("水")) {
            return 4;
        } else {
            return 0;// write default return here. If every condition goes false then this default will be return.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank You, By the way I have another one issue. Can share that with you?

Comment: @NithisKumar Of course. If another issue is not related to this question, you need to post it as new question.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of Strings in switch statements and return respective int values.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html

As we can't have mixed type for return value. You can consider 0(FALSE) and 1(TRUE). Or any such random value.

Answer (score 1):

Problem lies in this statement:

```
int equalsIgnoreCase2 = str.equalsIgnoreCase("火");
```

`equalsIgnoreCase()` method returns a `boolean` value and you are assigning it to an `int` value. That's why it is giving this error.

Answer (score 1):

Java is not a C language, so booleans cannot be integers, they are totally different types and cannot be mixed. In the 3rd line you are assigning boolean value to an int

Comment: So what I have to do to fix this. I'm newbie to Java

Comment: well why are you using integer "int equalsIgnoreCase2" instead of boolean?

Comment: This is not my code. this code was provided by my institute for exercise.