# incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to int

Tags: java

When I try to compile the following code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int newnumber = sumDigit(2);
        System.out.println(newnumber);
    }

    public static boolean sumDigit(int num) {
        if (num == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error message:

> Main.java:3: error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to int
>
> `int newnumber = sumDigit(2);`

Why?

Comment: `newnumber` has type of `int` but should have `boolean`

Comment: because `sumDigit` returns a boolean. This is not C++, you can't coerce a number into a boolean and vice-versa.

Comment: If you would ask me for a number and I would reply with "yes", would you consider that a valid answer or would you say "yes is not a number"?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/java/default.asp

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS it's evident you and, e.g., JavaScript have a different concept of what constitutes a valid answer to that question :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54034507/error-incompatible-types-boolean-cannot-be-converted-to-int)

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation

Your method is declared to return a `boolean`:

```
public static boolean sumDigit(int num) {
              ^^^^^^^
```

And you also return a `boolean`:

```
return true;
       ^^^^
```

But in your `main` method you are expecting an `int`:

```
int newnumber = sumDigit(2);
^^^
```

An `int` is a number, an integer, such as `1` or `2` or `3`. A `boolean` is jsut `true` or  `false`. You are comparing apples with oranges, that wont work.

---

### Solution

That said, according to your method name `sumDigit`, I suppose you intended to actually compute and return an `int` instead. So:

```
public static int sumDigit(int num) {
    int result = ...
    // compute the sum
    return result;
}
```

And then it will also compile and work.

In case you actually intended to return a `boolean`, I would suggest to rename the method to `isZero` to better indicate what it is actually computing:

```
public static boolean isZero(int num) {
    return num == 0;
}
```

But then you also have to change the type of the result you are expecting in `main`:

```
boolean result = isZero(2);
System.out.println(result); // false
```

No matter what you do, the types of what your method returns has to line up with the type that you are expexting as result.

---

### Other languages

Note that Java does not allow automatic conversion of `boolean` to `int` such as languages like **C++** that treat a `bool` as `0` or `1`. Java strictly differentiates them.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because of type incompatibility.
You try assign boolean value to int type.